Run a model and store its value to a variable
We execute one SQL with cursor and extract variable to set some variables in Snowflake. How to do it efficiently in dbt? Can I set values of variables from the results of a model?
def func() -> None:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = query_builder.prepare("""
             SELECT
                 1 AS FIRST_VALUE,
                 2 AS SECOND_VALUE
             FROM
                 my_table""")
    cursor.execute(query)
    if cursor.rowcount > 0:
        rows = cursor.fetchone()
        if rows[0] is not None:
            variable.set("var1", rows[0])
        else:
            variable.set("var1", 0)
        if rows[1] is not None:
            variable.set("var2", rows[1])
        else:
            variable.set("var2", 0)
    else:
        variable.set("var1", 0)   
        variable.set("var2", 0)


I have done it with this and it is working.
{% set query %}
    select * from {{ ref('set_variables') }}
{% endset %}

{% set results = run_query(query) %}

{% if execute %}
    {% set last_processed_week = results.columns[0][0] %}
    {% set current_process_week = results.columns[0][0] %}
    {{ print("Variable li_last_processed_week => " ~ last_processed_week)}}
    {{ print("Variable li_current_process_week => " ~ current_process_week)}}
{% endif %}

